# break long word into multiple lines

Tags: jquery, html, css, word-break

Can anyone please tell me some solution to break word like as shown below using css or jquery.

**SAMPLE 1**

```
ConfigTechnologyHormonyAppComponentBackOfficeLaunch
```

Need to break it into

```
ConfigTechnologyHo
rmonyAppComponentB
ackOfficeLaunch
```

**SAMPLE 2**

```
WorkAppComponentBackOfficeLaunchTechnologyNeteseen
```

Need to break it into

```
WorkAppComponentBa
ckOfficeLaunchTech
nologyNeteseen
```

**SAMPLE 3**

```
Supplement Hormony based on Continous Integration
```

Need to break it into

```
Supplement Hormony
based on Continous
Integration
```

I have tried with `word-break: break-all;` but its is not working

Comment: give the container or element a `max-width`

Comment: provide a code..so we can help you. what have you tried ??

Comment: Same demo from w3schools: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp

Comment: Is it coincidence that your last example appears to break on words rather than letters?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to specify a `max-width` according to your layout requirement for the text container.
Have a look:

CSS:

```
p {
  max-width: 100px;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

HTML:

```
<p>
ConfigTechnologyHormonyAppComponentBackOfficeLaunch
</p>
```

Comment: is there any way in which we can do the break without providing `max-width`

Comment: `word-break` works with bounded containers. If you can clearly specify what you're trying to achieve, maybe there could be another way. Semantically, this is the right way to do it.

Answer (score 5):

```css
.container{
  max-width:100px;
  border:thin black solid;
  word-break:break-all;
  height:auto;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">Config TechnologyHormonyApp ComponentBackOfficeLaunch</div>
```

Try this.

Hope this helps.

**PS:** change **container** `max-width` as per your need.

Comment: is there any way in which we can do the break without providing max-width

Comment: @AlexMan yes use width :))

Comment: @madalinivascu... agree with you.. @Alex Man you can use `width` , too. as , Tân Nguyễn has given you the `w3schools` example. in that , they have used `width`.

Answer (score 1):

**Try something like this:**

```css
.product-name a:before {
    content:"ConfigTechnologyHo \A rmonyAppComponentB \A ackOfficeLaunch ";
    white-space: pre;
    font-size:18px;
}
.product-name a {
    text-indent:-9999px;
    font-size:0;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="product-name"> 
  <a></a>
</h2>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with javascript

```
var text = 'WorkAppComponentBackOfficeLaunchTechnologyNeteseen';
var array = text.split('');
len = 18;//length of a single row

var newtext = '';
for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
   newtext +=array[i];
if (i % len == 0 && i>1) {
    newtext += '</br>';//or \n\r
    }
}
document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = newtext;
```